# RSS for Stackoverflow's unanswered questions that matches my only favorite tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, unanswered-questions, feed

While posting this questions I have tried to find an answer in other similar questions, but couldn't.

The question is:
Is there a RSS feed that I can subscribe to, which has newest unanswered questions of my favorite tags only?

Or maybe instead of favorite tags, I could decide which **"unanswered+tag+tag-tag"** combination I want?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's an RSS feed for unanswered questions.  If there is, there should be a link on the Unanswered/tagged pages, but I don't see one.

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+swing
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags

It does make sense that this information should only be served up on demand though, given the volatility of both tags and (particularly) Unanswered state.

Comment: Thanks for Answering.
Do you also happen to know if I can sort the questions in this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags
by "newest to oldest"?

Comment: @bits: It doesn't look like it.  I think the best you can do is specify tags on the newest tab.  http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/java+swing?tab=newest

Comment: Thanks! as a follow up, I have more "meta" questions popping up but the context is different. I will post them as a separate question later.

Comment: :D Makes life easier :D

Answer (score 1):

I have written an application that does just that by converting the JSON response of the API to an RSS feed:

[http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/logo.png](https://stackapps.com/questions/1599/stack2rss-a-json-to-rss-conversion-service)

An example feed that fetches all unanswered questions tagged `C` looks like this:

http://quickmediasolutions.com/stack2rss/stackoverflow/questions/unanswered?tagged=c&body=true

Hope that helps!